# How to get gridview cell value when i click on cell dynamically in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selection

I am developing a movie theater seats booking website,. I have placed images as `Seats` in `asp:gridview(all cells)` using `ImageButton`. For the selected seat, when the user clicks on it, the `ImageButton(cell)` is set for that seat.

I need to get the seat that was clicked from the `gridview`. How am I able to do this?

Comment: does jquery is ok here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ImageButton on the RowCommand event of the grid view.

Code part:

```
string strType="";
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
strType = img.Attributes["TypeID"].ToString();
```

Designer part:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="image"
 TypeID="..Give your value.." />
```